What is the name of the 2 episode series/movie where passengers disappear from a flight?
I remember around 15 years ago I watched a 2 episode movie/series about people disappearing on a flight.
I don't exactly remember how it started, I recall I watched some passengers on a flight who suddenly disappear with only a few left (the aircraft does not disappear). As the movie/short series carries on, the 'survivors' find out only the ones who were asleep in-flight did not disappear (bermuda triangle-like-movie). To get back to real life, the crew uses the plane's oxygen mask to induce sleep. Only one of the 'survivors' (who pilots the aircraft) 'sacrifices' himself in order to save everyone.
I saw this movie/series on national TV outside the US, I infer it might be older than that.

Such a great movie that people ask this multiple times a month :D

I tried my best searching here. Thanks!

You are thinking of The Langoliers from 1995, based on the Stephen King short story of the same name.
The plane flies through a rip in time, and all of the passengers who are not asleep disappear. The seven who remain find themselves stuck a few minutes in the past, but it is an empty world, waiting for the titular creatures to come along and devour it.
To return, they have to fly back through the rip, but again must be asleep. They turn the oxygen down to force themselves asleep, but one must stay awake to guide the plane through (and also turn the oxygen back up at the last minute so everyone doesn't die), thus sacrificing himself to save the rest.
